# Make a listener to know when exciting item is being updated in dynamodb

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDb table with about configuration details of my ios app.
In my app I retrieve all data in configuration table only when user launch app and store that data in my app for use it for necessary times.
Admin can changed configuration table manually.
I want to create listener. The listener's purpose is to detect when a table item is being updated and change the data which are my app is stored in user's launching time.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Dynamo streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on your table, then create a Lambda to process the stream.

The Lambda could place a notification on an SNS topic for your application.  SNS will use

- Amazon Device Messaging (ADM)
- Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) for both iOS and Mac OS X
- Baidu Cloud Push (Baidu)
- Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)
- Microsoft Push Notification Service for Windows Phone (MPNS)
- Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)

To [push the notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html#mobile-push-pseudo) to your users device.